# How to extract all tweets from multiple users' timelines using R?

Tags: python, r, twitter, twitter-rest-api, twitter-r

I am working on a project for which I want to extract the timelines of around 500 different twitter users (I am using this for historical analysis, so I'll only need to retrieve them all once- no need to update with incoming tweets).

While I know the Twitter API only allows the last 3,200 tweets to be retrieved, when I use the basic UserTimeline method of the R twitteR package, I only seem to fetch about 20 every time I try (for users with significantly more, recent, tweets). Is this because of rate limiting, or because I am doing something wrong?

Does anyone have tips for doing this most efficiently? I realize it might take a lot of time because of rate limiting, is there a way of automating/iterating this process in R?

I am quite stuck, so thank you very much for any help/tips you may have!

(I have some experience using the Twitter API/twitteR package to extract tweets using a certain hashtag over a couple of days. I have basic Python skills, if it turns out to be easier/quicker to do in Python).

Comment: It's probably because of paging. They're not going to send 3200 tweets over the wire at once. I would suggest trying to figure out how the twitter api performs paging and then going from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the [twitteR documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) suggests using the `maxID` argument for pagination. So when you get the first batch of results, you could use the minimum ID in that set minus one as the `maxID` for the next request, until you get no more results back (meaning you've gotten to the beginning of a user's timeline).

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.